# Getting the return value from a generator in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yield

I can't seem to figure out how to get at the return value of a generator - anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
function getGeneratorReturn() {
    var generator = runGenerator();
    var generatorReturn = null;

    var done = false;
    while(!done) {
        var currentNext = generator.next();
        console.log('Current next:', currentNext);
        generatorReturn = currentNext.value;
        done = currentNext.done;
    }

    return generatorReturn;
}

function* runGenerator() {
    var a = yield 1;
    var b = yield 2;
    var c = a + b;

    return c;
}

var generatorReturn = getGeneratorReturn();
console.log(generatorReturn); // Should output 3, is outputting NaN
```

Note: You'll need node 0.11.12 running with the --harmony option for this code to run.

Answer (score 15):

When `currentNext.done` is `true`, `curentNext.value` has the return value.

You can write your loop as:

```
var next;
while (!(next = generator.next()).done) {
    var yieldedValue = next.value;
}
var returnValue = next.value;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's because the yield expression will result in the value you pass to the generator, as you already noticed. You can circumvent that by using two statements: `var a = 1; yield a;`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work by passing the current value back into the generator when I call .next:

```
function getGeneratorReturn() {
    var generator = runGenerator();
    var generatorReturn = null;

    var done = false;
    while(!done) {
        var currentNext = generator.next(generatorReturn);
        console.log('Current next:', currentNext);
        generatorReturn = currentNext.value;
        done = currentNext.done;
    }

    return generatorReturn;
}

function* runGenerator() {
    var a = yield 1;
    var b = yield 2;
    var c = a + b;

    return c;
}

var generatorReturn = getGeneratorReturn();
console.log(generatorReturn); // Should output 3, is outputting NaN
```

Note: You'll need node 0.11.12 running with the --harmony option for this code to run.

Answer (score -2):

A generator function CANNOT `return` a value. 
Instead, a generator function *automagically* gets wrapped by an Iterator instance which gets returned.

Because a generator function is always executed asynchronously (triggered by `yield` statements or even by injecting values manually using `Iterator.next( value)` - see [this example](http://orangevolt.blogspot.de/2014/06/es6-super-minimalistic-example-how-to.html) ) the `return` statement can only be used to "close" the returned `Iterator` somewhere in your generator function code.

You can only "return" values from a generator function using `yield`.

Comment: This is false. Try some simple examples, like yield 1; return 2. The return value is available via next(), with done set to true.