# Generator return doesn't work in for-await-of loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, generator

Generator with `return` statement skips the execution of for-await-of loop.

```js
(async () => {
  const gen = async function* () {
     return { newState: "FAILURE" };
  };
  for await (const { newState } of gen()) {
    console.log("Yey! new state is:", newState);
    // do other stuff
  }
})();
```

In the case written above, the whole for-await-of construction will never console.log anything. But when you swap `return` for `yield` (`yield { newState: 'FAILURE' }`) everything work as intended.

```js
(async () => {
  const gen = async function* () {
    yield { newState: "FAILURE" };
  };
  for await (const { newState } of gen()) {
    console.log("Yey! new state is:", newState);
    // do other stuff
  }
})();
```

**WHY?**

Answer (score 1):

The iterator never yielded anything before completing, so the loop didn't have anything to iterate - the sequence was empty. Notice you can `yield` multiple times but `return` only once.

A `for … of` loop ignores the `return` value of an iterator. It's only useful when you are manually advancing the iterator, or when using `yield*`.

```js
async function* generate() {
  return { newState: "FAILURE" };
};
const generator = (async function*() {
  const { newState } = yield* generate()
  console.log("Yey! new state is:", newState);
  return "some value";
})();
generator.next().then(console.log);
```

This is no different for asynchronous iterators [than for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23418535/1048572) [synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47380067/1048572) [iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65871026/1048572).

Comment: Can you please provide some docs where explicitly said that/why the for-await-of ignores return?

Comment: @Src It doesn't ignore the `return` statement - it stops as expected. It just doesn't have anywhere to put the return *value* - a `for` loop is not an expression with a result value.

Comment: According to the docs, yield and return both returns values, but return instead of yield returns {done:true}. So why it isn’t act like yield in this case?

Comment: Also how loop knows when to stop, because if we swap return with yield, we still get the correct result, taking into account that we don’t manually said to stop iterating, which you normally do with return

Comment: "*return instead of yield returns {done:true}*" - yes, exactly. That signals the end of the iteration. Not the last value - otherwise you couldn't have an empty sequence. "*Why it isn’t act like yield*" - because it's `return`, not `yield`.

Comment: I think `return` in generator are not iteratable like `yield`. In object, we can define new custom property with `Object.defineProperty(obj, "propertyName", propertyDescriptorObject)` similarly may be `yield` is defined like iterable while `return` are not..(just came to mind).

Comment: @FaizanurRahman I don't understand what you are saying. Do you have a question, do you need some clarification?

Comment: @Bergi yes I have a question when do we need of return statement in generator. I mean  if we get return value from yield after each call to next then why do I write return statement in generator funciton?

Comment: @FaizanurRahman Simply because it's sometimes useful, mostly when using generators as coroutines that have a result, not when using them to iterate something.